# How can I locate the "Copyright" text?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm new in selenium and I'm trying to locate a part of text ("Copyright) from a website. If it exists the program will print "success", otherwise it will print "failed". There's a problem: I don't know how to locate that part of text. There's no class, no id, I don't have the code in CSS. I absolutely know nothing.

Here's the code I wrote, I made a few attempts

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

PATH = Service("/Users/fscozano/documenti/chromedriver-2.exe")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/random_apod.html")

try:
    # search1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/center[2]/b[2]")
    copyr = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Copyright").text
    # search = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(

    print(copyr)
    print("success")

except:
    print("failed")
    time.sleep(3)
```

How should I find "Copyright" if I know nothing and if it's part of a larger text?
You can look personally the website and find out where's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code/approach.

1. The text you want is inside an IFRAME. To allow Selenium to see inside an IFRAME, you need to switch context to that IFRAME. Best practice is to wait for the IFRAME to be available and then switch to it. See [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#moving-between-windows-and-frames).
2. Once you are inside that IFRAME, then you search for the desired element(s). One issue is that you haven't clearly defined what exactly you want as the output. Your code is attempting to retreive the `.text` from the "Copyright" element (which doesn't exist). Each time the page reloads, a different image is displayed and...

   1. It may or may not be copyrighted
   2. The copyright may or may not be a hyperlink
   3. The copyright may contain one or more links

   To make it all simpler, I'm going to give you code that gets all the text in the CENTER tag that contains the "Copyright" text when it exists e.g.,

   ```
   Our Rotating Earth
   Video Credit & Copyright: Bartosz Wojczyński
   ```
3. You should use `.find_elements` instead of `try-catch` because it doesn't involve throwing and catching exceptions. Exceptions should be exceptional (rare) and not (generally) be used as flow control.

Here's the updated code.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/random_apod.html")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,'apod')))
copyr = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//center[.//b[contains(.,'Copyright')]]")
if copyr:
    print(copyr)
    print("success")
else:
    print("failed")
```

I tried this a number of times and it worked but there may be examples out there that break this also.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using a wrong locator
2. You should add a wait to make this element completely loaded before accessing it
3. The element you are trying to access is out of the view, you need to scroll the page down
   This should work:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

PATH = Service("/Users/fscozano/documenti/chromedriver-2.exe")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/random_apod.html")
credit = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//b[contains(text(),'Credit')]/following-sibling::a")))
actions.move_to_element(credit).perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
credits = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//b[contains(text(),'Credit')]/following-sibling::a")
for credit in credits:
    print(credit.text)
```

Comment: It doesen't work. The error is in copyright = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//center[./b[contains(text(),'Copyright')]]//a")))

Comment: What error do you see? Timeout, invalid syntax etc?

Comment: TiemoutException

Comment: OK, I see. It changes from picture to picture. Sometimes it is only credit, in other times it is credit and copyright of the same person in the same element, sometimes credit for one person and the copyright for other etc... You should define your task better

Comment: So, can you help me?

Comment: With the pleasure, but you have to define the task clearly.

Comment: OO, looks like I found the solution that will work for all the cases since 'Credits' will appear for all the cases. In several cases there are several credits texts so I made it to print all the credits.

Comment: I'm sorry saying this again, but there's another TimeoutException in credit = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//b[contains(text(),'Credit')]/following-sibling::a")))

Comment: Are you sure you copied exactly what I wrote?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: Sounds very strange.

Comment: I know, but I can't figure out where the problem is. I trust you for any tips or other things, you're the expert

Comment: Anyway, if you have something else to recommend to me I'm all ears. Otherwise that's not a problem, you have been a great help for me. Thanks

Comment: OK, sure. But currently I can't think about why didn't this worked for you